# Rails route helpers - one model to fill many params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, helper

I have the following route:

```
get "/:user_name/things/:thing_name" => "things#show", :as => "show_user_thing"
```

`Thing` belongs to `user`. So with just an instance of `thing` I have both parameters. However, when using the route helpers, I'm forced to specify each segment separately like so:

```
show_user_thing_path(@thing.user, @thing)
```

This sucks. I'd much rather do just this:

```
show_user_thing_path(@thing)
```

But how do I do this the 'route helper way'? I'd love to still use all the rails goodies for route's like these. Any ideas?

Comment: I am curious why you need the username in the route at all since you are pulling the user from the thing anyway. Why not `/things/:thing_name`

Comment: @natedavisolds because I'm using slugs that may collide with each other unless in the user's namespace. Put another way, many users can have things with the same name.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll take a shot at the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your pain.  In the cases where I uses the url helper a lot, I just write my own helper.

```
def show_thing_by_user_path(thing)
    show_user_thing_path(thing.user, thing)
end
```

Of course you'd have to modify it slightly to include any options and formatting, but I think you get the idea of what I'm saying.

Comment: Is there a standard place to put these route specific helpers?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Helpers are pretty disorganized. I'm how that the rails team will handle it similar to asset management. Hmmm.. maybe it is a good discussion/contribution topic.

Comment: Although, I would consider a `routes_helper.rb` file in the helper directory a good candidate.

Comment: A helper appears to be the only way to do this as of rails 3.1. This is something I'll consider patching.

Comment: @TheDeeno, if you find any more info, or a better/more idiomatic way of handling this, please update us! I'm struggling with the same thing now. 

While `thing_path(@user, @thing)` or `thing_path(@thing.user, @thing)` is doable, it's not very beautiful.

Also, are you using nested resources:
`resources :users do
  resources :things
end`

or a route prefix via named parameter:
`scope ":username: do
  resources :things
end`

Comment: @TheDeeno I threw a Gist up showing what I have to do now, and what I want to be doing: https://gist.github.com/1034653

Comment: @stevenharman - I hear you. It would be nice to have routes that could sense relationships, but is this an exception more than the standard convention? Should we extend Rails core to make this happen? At first I thought it would get in the way too much but now... I think that I will look into it too.